# Jenkins' variable for the directory of external tool

Tags: jenkins

I need to run a external tools before Jenkins build, I write a .bat file (in Windows) and it works. My question is, I need to setup the entire path of the bat file (ex: C:\CI\Tools\MyBatch.bat).

Is it possible to let the path to be a variable? For example, I use "${TOOL_PATH}\MyBatch.bat" in my project configuration and configure TOOL_PATH in Jenkins' configuration. I try to set a variable, but it doesn't work.

My requirement is when I move MyBatch.bat to another directory, I don't need to modify lots of project. And if it can let slaves to use the same configuration, it's better, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).

I believe you can either define

- Global environment variables

  Manage Jenkins / Configure System

  then Global properties / Environment Variables

  ( http://$host/configure )
- or node specific variables (even for your master if your use it as build machine)

  Manage Jenkins / Manage Nodes / Configure

  then Node properties / Environment Variables

  ( http://$host/computer/($nodename)/configure )

Don't forget environment variables in Windows are interpolated using %VARIABLE% not $VARIABLE.

Comment: I use ${VARIABLE} originally and it works after I change it to %VARIABLE%, thanks.